# Mercurial server on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial

My Mercurial server is not working.

When I access this page `127.0.0.1/mercurial` the following text appears:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# An example hgweb CGI script, edit as necessary
# See also http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories

# Path to repo or hgweb config to serve (see 'hg help hgweb')
config = "/var/www/hgweb.config"

# Uncomment and adjust if Mercurial is not installed system-wide
# (consult "installed modules" path from 'hg debuginstall'):
#import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/python/lib")

# Uncomment to send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
#import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb, wsgicgi
application = hgweb(config)
wsgicgi.launch(application)
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/mercurial-server-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-with-web-access/).

I configured the server in the directory `/var/www/`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apache is interpreting your .cgi file as a text file to serve, not a problem to run.   Most likely the `ScriptAliasMatch` or some module necessary to make it work is missing or you don't have execute permissions set for the cgi file.  This should be over on server fault -- it's about server administration not software development, and you'll probably get more detailed answers there.

Comment: yeah, not having CGI enabled would sure do it. :)